# Sunrise and sunset times based on coordinates and altitude

Tags: c++, visual-c++, time

I am using this code for calculating sunrise and sunset times.

```
// Get the daylight status of the current time.
bool
SunLight::CalculateDaylightStatus()
{
   // Calculate the current time of day.
   time_t currentTime = time(NULL);
   m_LocalTime = localtime(&currentTime);

   // Initialize the sunrise and set times.
   *m_Sunrise = *m_LocalTime;
   *m_Sunset = *m_LocalTime;

   // Flags to check whether sunrise or set available on the day or not.
   m_IsSunrise = false;
   m_IsSunset = false;

   m_RiseAzimuth = 0.0;
   m_SetAzimuth = 0.0;

   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
      m_RightAscention[i] = 0.0;
      m_Decension[i] = 0.0;
      m_VHz[i] = 0.0;
   }

   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
      m_SunPositionInSky[i] = 0.0;
      m_RiseTime[i] = 0;
      m_SetTime[i] = 0;
   }

   // Calculate the sunrise and set times.
   CalculateSunRiseSetTimes();

   return (mktime(m_LocalTime) >= mktime(m_Sunrise) && mktime(m_LocalTime) < mktime(m_Sunset))
         ? true
         : false;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

bool
SunLight::CalculateSunRiseSetTimes()
{
   double zone = timezone/3600 - m_LocalTime->tm_isdst;

   // Julian day relative to Jan 1.5, 2000.
   double jd = GetJulianDay() - 2451545;

   if ((Sign(zone) == Sign(m_Config->Longitude())) && (zone != 0))
   {
      return false;
   }

   double tz = zone / 24;

   // Centuries since 1900.0
   double ct = jd / 36525 + 1;

   // Local sidereal time.
   double t0 = LocalSiderealTimeForTimeZone(jd, tz, m_Config->Longitude()/360);

   // Get sun position at start of day.
   jd += tz;

   // Calculate the position of the sun.
   CalculateSunPosition(jd, ct);

   double ra0 = m_SunPositionInSky[0];
   double dec0 = m_SunPositionInSky[1];

   // Get sun position at end of day.
   jd += 1;

   // Calculate the position of the sun.
   CalculateSunPosition(jd, ct);

   double ra1 = m_SunPositionInSky[0];
   double dec1 = m_SunPositionInSky[1];

   // make continuous
   if (ra1 < ra0)
      ra1 += 2 * M_PI;

   m_RightAscention[0] = ra0;
   m_Decension[0] = dec0;

   // check each hour of this day
   for (int k = 0; k < 24; k++)
   {
      m_RightAscention[2] = ra0 + (k + 1) * (ra1 - ra0) / 24;
      m_Decension[2] = dec0 + (k + 1) * (dec1 - dec0) / 24;
      m_VHz[2] = TestHour(k, t0, m_Config->Latitude());

      // advance to next hour
      m_RightAscention[0] = m_RightAscention[2];
      m_Decension[0] = m_Decension[2];
      m_VHz[0] = m_VHz[2];
   }

   // Update the tm structure with time values.
   m_Sunrise->tm_hour = m_RiseTime[0];
   m_Sunrise->tm_min = m_RiseTime[1];

   m_Sunset->tm_hour = m_SetTime[0];
   m_Sunset->tm_min = m_SetTime[1];

   // neither sunrise nor sunset
   if ((!m_IsSunrise) && (!m_IsSunset))
   {
      // Sun down all day.
      if (m_VHz[2] < 0)
         m_IsSunset = true;

      // Sun up all day.
      else
         m_IsSunrise = true;
   }
   return true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

int
SunLight::Sign(double value)
{
   if (value > 0.0)
      return 1;
   else if (value < 0.0)
      return -1;
   else
      return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

// Local Sidereal Time for zone.
double
SunLight::LocalSiderealTimeForTimeZone(double jd, double z, double lon)
{
   double s = 24110.5 + 8640184.812999999 * jd / 36525 + 86636.6 * z + 86400 * lon;
   s = s / 86400;
   s = s - floor(s);
   return s * 360 * cDegToRad;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

// Determine Julian day from calendar date
// (Jean Meeus, "Astronomical Algorithms", Willmann-Bell, 1991).
double
SunLight::GetJulianDay()
{
   int month = m_LocalTime->tm_mon + 1;
   int day = m_LocalTime->tm_mday;
   int year = 1900 + m_LocalTime->tm_year;

   bool gregorian = (year < 1583) ? false : true;

   if ((month == 1) || (month == 2))
   {
      year = year - 1;
      month = month + 12;
   }

   double a = floor((double)year / 100);
   double b = 0;

   if (gregorian)
      b = 2 - a + floor(a / 4);
   else
      b = 0.0;

   double jd = floor(365.25 * (year + 4716))
         + floor(30.6001 * (month + 1))
         + day + b - 1524.5;

   return jd;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

// Sun's position using fundamental arguments
// (Van Flandern & Pulkkinen, 1979).
void
SunLight::CalculateSunPosition(double jd, double ct)
{
   double g, lo, s, u, v, w;

   lo = 0.779072 + 0.00273790931 * jd;
   lo = lo - floor(lo);
   lo = lo * 2 * M_PI;

   g = 0.993126 + 0.0027377785 * jd;
   g = g - floor(g);
   g = g * 2 * M_PI;

   v = 0.39785 * sin(lo);
   v = v - 0.01 * sin(lo - g);
   v = v + 0.00333 * sin(lo + g);
   v = v - 0.00021 * ct * sin(lo);

   u = 1 - 0.03349 * cos(g);
   u = u - 0.00014 * cos(2 * lo);
   u = u + 0.00008 * cos(lo);

   w = -0.0001 - 0.04129 * sin(2 * lo);
   w = w + 0.03211 * sin(g);
   w = w + 0.00104 * sin(2 * lo - g);
   w = w - 0.00035 * sin(2 * lo + g);
   w = w - 0.00008 * ct * sin(g);

   // compute sun's right ascension
   s = w / sqrt(u - v * v);
   m_SunPositionInSky[0] = lo + atan(s / sqrt(1 - s * s));

   // ...and declination
   s = v / sqrt(u);
   m_SunPositionInSky[1] = atan(s / sqrt(1 - s * s));
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

// Test an hour for an event.
double
SunLight::TestHour(int k, double t0, double prmLatitude)
{
   double ha[3];
   double a, b, c, d, e, s, z;
   double time;
   double az, dz, hz, nz;
   int hr, min;

   ha[0] = t0 - m_RightAscention[0] + k * cK1;
   ha[2] = t0 - m_RightAscention[2] + k * cK1 + cK1;

   ha[1] = (ha[2] + ha[0]) / 2;    // hour angle at half hour
   m_Decension[1] = (m_Decension[2] + m_Decension[0]) / 2;  // declination at half hour

   s = sin(prmLatitude * cDegToRad);
   c = cos(prmLatitude * cDegToRad);
   z = cos(90.833 * cDegToRad);    // refraction + sun semi-diameter at horizon

   if (k <= 0)
      m_VHz[0] = s * sin(m_Decension[0]) + c * cos(m_Decension[0]) * cos(ha[0]) - z;

   m_VHz[2] = s * sin(m_Decension[2]) + c * cos(m_Decension[2]) * cos(ha[2]) - z;

   if (Sign(m_VHz[0]) == Sign(m_VHz[2]))
      return m_VHz[2];  // no event this hour

   m_VHz[1] = s * sin(m_Decension[1]) + c * cos(m_Decension[1]) * cos(ha[1]) - z;

   a = 2 * m_VHz[0] - 4 * m_VHz[1] + 2 * m_VHz[2];
   b = -3 * m_VHz[0] + 4 * m_VHz[1] - m_VHz[2];
   d = b * b - 4 * a * m_VHz[0];

   if (d < 0)
      return m_VHz[2];  // no event this hour

   d = sqrt(d);
   e = (-b + d) / (2 * a);

   if ((e > 1) || (e < 0))
      e = (-b - d) / (2 * a);

   time = (double)k + e + (double)1 / (double)120; // time of an event

   hr = (int)floor(time);
   min = (int)floor((time - hr) * 60);

   hz = ha[0] + e * (ha[2] - ha[0]);                 // azimuth of the sun at the event
   nz = -cos(m_Decension[1]) * sin(hz);
   dz = c * sin(m_Decension[1]) - s * cos(m_Decension[1]) * cos(hz);
   az = atan2(nz, dz) / cDegToRad;
   if (az < 0) az = az + 360;

   if ((m_VHz[0] < 0) && (m_VHz[2] > 0))
   {
      m_RiseTime[0] = hr;
      m_RiseTime[1] = min;
      m_RiseAzimuth = az;
      m_IsSunrise = true;
   }

   if ((m_VHz[0] > 0) && (m_VHz[2] < 0))
   {
      m_SetTime[0] = hr;
      m_SetTime[1] = min;
      m_SetAzimuth = az;
      m_IsSunset = true;
   }

   return m_VHz[2];
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to introduce altitude in the formula which gives more accurate result. Can someone give me a quick solution what I have to modify to add altitude in the formula?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not going to read all of that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/182647). Can you express your problem more compactly in mathematical form instead of as code?

Comment: As far as I understand, this is not programming related, despite the amount of code inculded in the question.

Answer (score 2):

That algorithm is nowhere near calculating the times of sunrise and sunset. What you need is [Jean Meeus' book "Astronomical Algorithms"](http://www.willbell.com/math/mc1.HTM). You will need to account for the observer's longitude and latitude, the difference between dynamical time and universal time, and the eccentricity of the Earth's orbit to obtain even a low accuracy result.

Comment: You need to spell out "this" so that this answer will still be useful when the link goes dead.

Comment: @Dabbler Well, the algorithm is giving me the exact result and I have given the algorithm references. I have a requirement of calculating these times by considering the altitude as well.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be called [sunrise equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation). The formulas in that Wiki article are unbelievably simple, and they do account for the geographic location.

Comment: The OP asks for inclusion of altitude (meaning: above sea level, if I understand correctly) in the algorithm. Geographic location is not the same as altitude.

Comment: @bartovan: ouch, I must have missed that. There are formulae for calculating the distance to horizon based on observer's elevation. Those can be used to re-calculate the coordinates before invoking the sunrise equation (if you see N meters further beyond the horizon based on your elevation, it's equivalent to observing from flat surface N meters to the west for sunrise and to the east for sunset), but there must be a more direct way.

Comment: P. S. I've got sunrise and sunset reversed there, obviously.